# logback: AsyncAppender takes more time than Synchronous FileAppender

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am seeing logback asynchronous logging provides worse performance than synchronous logging. Details below.

What could I be missing?

**Test Class:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class Main extends Thread {

    public static final Logger defaultLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Main().start();
        System.out.println("... Thread started\n");

        // This is to block till thread finishes writing
        System.in.read();
    }

    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {          
            defaultLogger.warn("Default logger:");
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("\n**** " + new Long(end - start));
    }
}
```

**logback.xml:**

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="DEFAULT-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <file>logger.log</file>
        <encoder charset="UTF-8">
            <pattern>[%date] [%thread] %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DEFAULT-ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <!-- Have tried to play around with queue size - no major effect -->
        <!-- <queueSize>512</queueSize>  -->
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT-FILE" />
    </appender>

    <root level="all">
        <!-- Switch between the two appenders -->
        <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT-FILE" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT-ASYNC" /> -->
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**Observations:**

> Sync FileAppender: ~5000ms
>   AsyncAppender: ~7000ms

**Versions:**

> slf4j: 1.7.19
>   logback: 1.1.6

Comment: Have you tried a queue size of 1000000? Otherwise your measuring code forces a queue resize which may be the main problem for the bad timing... Furthermore you should make multiple measurements in the same JVM instance and discard the first one because it may be tainted because of class and buffer initialization times.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Queue size needs to be sufficiently large, else the logging is blocked when the queue is full and is being cleared by worker (There is no queue resize. Logging is slower because of blocking.) This is mentioned in the [documentation] (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

`By default, event queue is configured with a maximum capacity of 256 events. If the queue is filled up, then application threads are blocked from logging new events until the worker thread has had a chance to dispatch one or more events.`

Comment: @Robert if you can add it as answer, I will accept it

Comment: There are some better benchmarks here: http://blog.takipi.com/how-to-instantly-improve-your-java-logging-with-7-logback-tweaks/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One problem of your code is that you are creating 1000000 logging entries in a very short time, however the AsyncAppender has a queue with a maximum capacity of 256 (default).

Therefore as a first step you have to increase the queue size to 1000000. Otherwise the time you measure is invalid.

Furthermore you should make multiple measurements in the same JVM instance and discard the first one because it may be tainted because of class and buffer initialization times.